# Is it possible to completely puncture a human hand and have no blood come out?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, hematology, veins

Illusionist David Blaine sometimes performs a trick where he takes a very long and thin ice pick, insterts it in his hand, and comes out the other side (the palm). However, there is no blood present. Is this possible at all? (Warning: Graphic Content) [Here is the video](https://youtu.be/udHdhmhToUc?t=3m45s) (already timestamped)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

The needle should be passed through **[Fistula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fistula)**, which is an abnormal or surgically made entry between an empty or tubular organ and the body surface, or between two empty or tubular organs.

According to **[Magic Secrets Explained](http://www.secrets-explained.com/david-blaine/ricky-gervais-needle-trick)** >>

> This provides us with a reasonable explanation for Blaine's needle
> trick. He has a **fistula** through his arm. He created this **fistula** to
> himself, by *repeatedly causing small damage to his arm in the same
> direction*, probably by actually stabbing a needle into it.
>
> He basically drilled a tube of ***scar tissue*** through his arm just so he could perform this one trick.

In order to further cement their logic, they attached another **[video](https://youtu.be/tnBjbgliMMM)** of a man who had a fistula through his body which empowered him to have swords cut through his body without hurting him.

**Fistulas** are also incorporated in *dialysis*, and infact referred to as dialyses’ lifeline. An article by **[Big D and Me](https://bigdandme.blog/2011/08/19/dialysis-fistulas-and-fatal-haemorrhages/)** expands more on this plus explains how it also threatens lives.